# How to understand what is going on in line line 23 of the for loop initilization

Tags: java

I need help in understanding why we initialize the for loop at line 23 to `(size / 2) - 1`. I understand this entire for loop is controlling the printing for the 2nd half of the hour glass but why is that specific initialization necessary. I thought if in order to print the 2nd half we would have to pick up where we left off at `size / 2`. The `int i` would be 1 in the code for its first iteration and that doesn't make any sense to me, shouldn't it be 2 if the first half starts at 0?

Actual problem being worked:

> Define a method called drawHourClass that draws an hour glass with a specific number of lines. For example, calling `drawHourClass(4)` will draw the following diagram:
>
> ```
> ****
>  ** 
>  ** 
> ****
> ```

```
public class Hour_Glass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Hour_Glass hourGlass = new Hour_Glass();
        hourGlass.drawHourGlass(4);
    }

    public void drawHourGlass(int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < size - (i * 2); k++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < i; l++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = ((size / 2) - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < size - (i * 2); k++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < i; l++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Since the loop is going until `<= 0`, the loop will iterate twice if `i == 1`

Comment: Hint: it is always fair to ask for explanations, but the real joy of learning to program is: finding out yourself. And that might include the path of asking "heck, how could I find out". And the first answer to that would be: start playing with the code. Just change that condition, and see what happens! Having said that: a nice question for a newbie!

Answer (score 0):

The second for i loop moves back through the same numbers that the first one moved through but in the opposite direction. The last time i processed anything it was at (size / 2) - 1 and it jumped out of the loop at (size / 2). So the second loop starts at (size / 2) - 1 and jumps out when it gets to -1.

Answer (score 0):

For size of 4, the top loop is going to produce two lines of output:

```
i == 0
i == 1
```

The second loop is also going to produce two lines of output:

```
i == 1
i == 0
```

And the code inside each is duplicated, so you get your four lines as in your example.

I'm not sure the confusion. In the top loop, you're going to loop with i starting at zero and going to (size/2) - 1 (because of the < comparison in the for statement). The second one is going to go from (size/2)-1 to 0. So the same thing but in the opposite direction.